# Why a float is required?

Tags: python

There is a code:

```
from arcpy.sa import *

arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")


print "Creating and defining X and Y coordinates:"  #set env properties
env.workspace = r"C:\Users\Desktop\data\new"
env.overwriteOutput = 1


theme = '/watersheds_3D.shp' #polygons in vector format

demName = '/demlab4'  # raster of DEM
rasObject = Raster(demName)


my_extent = rasObject.extent #find a grid cell size:
my_cellsize = (rasObject.meanCellHeight + rasObject.meanCellWidth)/2
print my_cellsize

slope_deg = Slope(demName)
slope_deg.save('/demlab4_slope')

for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(theme, ["FID","SHAPE@"]):  # inside shp file - 
    print ("Polygon # {}: ".format(row[0]))

    for part in row[1]:  # Inside the polygon

        xCoords = []
        yCoords = [] 
        zCoords = [] 
        for pnt in part:

            print (" {}, {}, {} ".format(pnt.X, pnt.Y, pnt.Z))
            xCoords.append(pnt.X)
            yCoords.append(pnt.Y)
            zCoords.append(pnt.Z) 

        area3D = lab4_arcpy_module.define3Darea(my_cellsize, slope_deg)
```

and function to calculate this:

```
def define3Darea(my_cellsize, slope_deg): 

    a = my_cellsize
    slope_rad = math.pi * slope_deg / 180 # return in radiant
    c = math.sqrt(a**2 + (math.tan(slope_rad)*a)**2)

    area3D = a*c
    print "Total 3D Area is: ", area3D, "m^2"

    return area3D
```

it gives: TypeError: a float is required.
What can be a problem?

Also need to calculate 3D Area inside the each polygon (4). How t do it?

Comment: You really need to provide the full error message so we can see where the error occurred. Context is everything!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what `Raster` and `Slope` are doing, but this `TypeError: a float is required` comes when you try to some float operations on a variable that is not of float type. My guess would be that problem is with : `slope_deg` variable. See here :

```
slope_deg = Slope(demName)
slope_deg.save('/demlab4_slope')
```

You are declaring and doing some operation with `slope_deg` variable. And now in this statement:

```
area3D = lab4_arcpy_module.define3Darea(my_cellsize, slope_deg)
```

you are using same variable which is an instance of `Slope` class and not a float variable. Either there has to be some attribute of this(`Slope`) which is  `float` or you have to use correct variable.

Answer (score 0):

i found that theres is some error trying to print loss so:

```
print ("Model paramters:" )      
print ("Weight:%f" %sess.run(W))
print ("bias:%f" %sess.run(b))
#print ("loss:%f" %(loss)) <------
```

make the error disapear, still don't understand well why is this.